# WHERE Clause does not accept just defined column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This Code does not work:

```
SELECT 
( 
    SELECT [T_Licence].[isInstalled]    
    FROM [T_Licence]    
    WHERE [T_Licence].[System]  = [T_System].[ID]   
    AND [T_Licence].[Software] = 750
) AS [IsInstalled] ,*
FROM [T_System]
WHERE [IsInstalled] = 1
```

I have to do it this way, but this makes the whole code so complicated. I really dont want that:

```
SELECT 
( 
    SELECT [T_Licence].[isInstalled]    
    FROM [wf_subj_all].[T_Licence]  
    WHERE [T_Licence].[System]  = [T_System].[ID]   
    AND [T_Licence].[Software] = 750
) AS [IsInstalled] ,*
FROM [wf_subj_it].[T_System]
WHERE 
(
    SELECT 
    ( 
        SELECT [T_Licence].[isInstalled]    
        FROM [wf_subj_all].[T_Licence]  
        WHERE [T_Licence].[System]  = [T_System].[ID]   
        AND [T_Licence].[Software] = 750
    )
) = 1
```

Is there any way to do it like shown in the first code snippet?
So that the code stays somehow readeble.

thx very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT *
FROM wf_subj_it.T_System s
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT /*TOP(1)*/ t.isInstalled   
    FROM wf_subj_all.T_Licence t
    WHERE t.[System]  = s.ID   
    AND t.Software = 750
) t
WHERE t.isInstalled = 1
```

Comment: thx  ! :) I just added  t.isInstalled to SELECT as first column and it gives the same table.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap the query with an outer select and it should work.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT 
  ( 
    SELECT [T_Licence].[isInstalled]    
    FROM [T_Licence]    
    WHERE [T_Licence].[System]  = [T_System].[ID]   
    AND [T_Licence].[Software] = 750
  ) AS [IsInstalled], *
  FROM [T_System]
) As tbl1
WHERE [IsInstalled] = 1
```

Comment: In this case we can get `Subquery returned more than 1 value`, so `TOP(1)` is necessary for subquery

Comment: @Devart Yes, and an `order by` to determine which of the rows to return in case of many. Of course  if we know this will never happen it is not required to be added.

Answer (score 0):

The assumptions I made for my answer:

- You're trying to select the systems (table T_System) which have software with id=750 installed
- The table T_License contains the installed information
- There is a 1:n relation between T_System and T_License: T_License may contain 0, 1 or more records per Sytem value...
- but the combination System plus Software is unique

I think this will work

```
SELECT l.[isInstalled], s.*
FROM   [wf_subj_it].[T_System] AS s
       INNER JOIN [wf_subj_it].[T_License] AS l
       ON  l.[System] = s.[ID]
       AND l.[Software] = 750
       AND l.isInstalled = 1
```

Comment: I tried it with INNER JOIN first, but it did not work, because if I set isInstalled = 0 there are systems missing in the table.   If a software is not insalled the Licence table not necessarily has a row about that. It even did not work with LEFT JOIN, and  adding l.isInsalled IS NULL, because it my not be NULL because there are rows for other Software.

Comment: Then I assume you want a list of all systems, with a 0 for isInstalled on systems where software with id 750 is not installed. In that case, I think this should do the trick: 
`SELECT ISNULL(l.[isInstalled], 0) AS isInstalled, s.*
 FROM   [wf_subj_it].[T_System] AS s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [wf_subj_it].[T_License] AS l
       ON  l.[System] = s.[ID]
       AND l.[Software] = 750`

if there is no record in T_License with System=T_System.ID and Software=750, l.[isInstalled] will be NULL, which is equivalent to "not installed".

Comment: No this wont work eather because, there are still datarows missing. All the systems that have licences for some software but not the one with id 750 are missing then.

Comment: I checked the query with a testscript and it runs as I expected, showing systems with software 750 installed, systems with software 750 and isInstalled=0, systems with other software, systems with Software is NULL and systems without any software records. I suspect that you have an extra inner join in the actual query, which causes this. 
If you have for example an extra join from T_License to a T_Software table to look up the name of the software, this join must also be a left join, otherwise the left join from T_System to T_License will effectively become an inner join.